# Value changes in the controller in the directive

Tags: angularjs

Hey I have button with function ng-click how can I change property $scope.actual which is in controller of directive?

```
demo
```

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/WXKvYM

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a function to ng-click that should be called when you click . Inside the function implementation you need to change the actual value

Comment: But button is out of controller in which I want to change variable

Comment: You should put your button inside the directive ideally ..Is it something not possible

Comment: for example I have component/directive sidebar, I have buton to toggle him, I cant put him inside directive. Seriously is no way to pass parameter to this controller ?

Comment: A directive has its own controller , there can be inheritance concept coming up here if there is no child  $scope here , it will look into its parent controller then